# Is there a single word to express hiding the truth 'for the greater good'?

Tags: single-word-requests

In short, a word or verb that qualifies an action for someone who keeps the truth covered up, NOT necessarily with ill intent, but to 'protect' people from fear, anxiety, or from flipping out?

---

Weather Vane, thank you, i like "misdirection" it sounds like a good fit as well, although it could equally be for either good or bad intentions. Edwind Ashworth's "need-to-know" seems appropriate as well, only if it's not to just PRETEND that it's hidden for the greater good. All in all, i think the winner might be @Timfoil Hat's "Guarded truth"

Comment: hi everyone, i'm from Europe but living in the States for a number of years now. Still learning & discovering the subtleties of the English vocabulary. So, thank you to anyone willing to help me perfect my practice of this most useful language!

Comment: [Read this](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for how to ask a question.

Comment: I don’t have a verb... But if it’s not a complete cover up, I would call it *guarded* — as in a *guarded truth*.

Comment: Restricted information is said to be released on a **need-to-know** basis. But It's hypernymic, often this is to protect self interest rather than maintain the general good.

Comment: thank you guys, i kind of like "guarded truth", seems to fit

Comment: A *white lie* is something told with good intent, but the OP seems to want either a verb or a qualifier (adverb or adjective), not a noun phrase.

Comment: Please ask @TinfoilHat to post an answer, so you can accept their answer and award the user the green check, and 15 rep points. P.S I find it almost counterproductive that a mod, of all people, would edit the post and incorporate the OP's "answer"–now deleted– in the actual question itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those concepts that doesn't really have a single word to describe it.

Whereas languages like German are pretty good at finding single words to describe complicated concepts or contexts, English falls short of that ability quite frequently and a quick description or a phrase is needed to ensure that the reader or conversation partner understands what you are talking about.

Some words like *Omit*/*Omission*, *redact*/*redaction*, and *censor* almost fit, but additional context would be needed to avoid ambiguity.

**If you have a definition in your head but cannot quite think of the word, I highly recommend the website https://onelook.com/thesaurus/.**

It's a reverse dictionary, and all you have to do is type a description of the word, and it will give you a list of words that best fit your definition. It has saved me many, many times. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but the phrase

> **economical** with the truth

has been widely used. [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/economical+with+the+truth) says

> The phrase economy of truth was used in the 18th century by the orator Edmund Burke ( 1729–97 ), while in the 19th century Mark Twain observed ‘Truth is the most valuable thing we have. Let us economize it’ (Following the Equator, 1897 ).
>
> The present phrase became current after its use in the ‘Spycatcher’ trial in the New South Wales Supreme Court: Robert Armstrong , head of the British Civil Service, was reported as saying of a letter: ‘It contains a misleading impression, not a lie. It was being economical with the truth.’

Comment: When it takes that number of words to express, it is a sure sign the author feels the pinch of dishonesty in the back of their neck.

Comment: A single word could be [misdirection](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misdirection) – the action of making people pay attention to the wrong thing, usually intentionally so that they will not notice something else.

Comment: that's great, thank you, "economical" is very neutral, kind of excusing the hiding of the truth, however fitting the 'well intentioned' part of it, although the Mark Twain quote seems to outrightly contradict the very purpose of the truth...

Comment: Weather Vane, thank you, i like "misdirection" it sounds like a good fit as well, although it could equally be for either good or bad intentions. Edwind Ashworth's "need-to-know" seems appropriate as well, only if it's not to just PRETEND that it's hidden for the greater good. All in all, i think the winner might be @Timfoil Hat's "Guarded truth"   

Answer (score 0):

The word could be "dissimulation."

It means hiding or disguising thoughts or feelings, but it doesn't necessarily imply doing it for a good cause.

Cambridge Dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dissimulation